# Best Way to Save a Font in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fonts

Which is the best way to insert a font in a SQL Server database, while knowing that this font can accessed from different environments (Windows/Linux) and languages (Java/PHP/Python/C#)?

I have a case where I should insert a Font from a C# Winforms application and get this font from Java application, and currently I'm inserting `Font.Name`, `Font.Style` and `Font.Size` and from Java I'm retrieving the font using `Font.Decode();` method.

And it works in many cases, but I thought it might be better to transfer the font file to the database and get the font file `.ttf` from the database by associating a custom constructed string to identify the font with its associated file.

eg: `Font Name`, `Font Size` and `Font Style` + `Font File`, because sometimes that font is not installed or has a different name on another system (font is very important in my case).

Comment: A font file is a file like any other binary file - just store it like any other binary file (there are **tons** of questions here and articles elsewhere showing how to do this in great detail). **However:** I'm not sure this is a good idea - after all, a font often needs to be **installed** on the target system before it can be used, so I'm not sure it helps if your Java app just grabs the file - I don't think this will be enough to make the font work on that system....

Comment: @marc_s im sure about the Font File ,and that's not my concern ,my concern is Should I or Should i NOT ,and i clarified why !And what i need is an Idea or If someone has a Already made Solution how to Tell Java and others which Font to use .

Comment: @marc_s: I believe it is possible for Java's graphics library to load a font file from the file system (or more likely a byte stream in this situation) and subsequently use it within the application via `Font java.awt.Font.createFont(int fontFormat, InputStream in);` or `Font java.awt.Font.createFont(int fontFormat, File fontFile);` I'm not sure about the other languages.

Comment: I would add, that just because a font exists on a system does not mean that it is freely distributable to other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database VARBINARY column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's FILESTREAM attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee foto in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee foto, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it "LARGE_DATA".

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store VARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX) columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
     (....... define the fields here ......)
     ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
     TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!

Comment: Nice thing +1 i`ll analyze it.