# Web application to accept Tamil font

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just developing a web application using ASP.Net, which accepts TAMIL font. Here, if I type something in the textbox in tamil, it should be getting saved with the same values whatever I type in it.

For this I just changed the font style of that textbox to BAMINI, with this BAMINI style I can type the words in Tamil, but when I debug the code, the value of the textbox is showing in English only, but I want it should be in Tamil only.

I thought I can fix this by using CultureInfo, and I tried with that. But its not happening. How can I fix this. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance

here is my Style for the textbox,

```
.tamilTextBox
{
font-family: bamini;
font-size: large;
font-style: oblique;
width: 50%;
}
```

and in the code behind am trying like this,

```
customer.FirstName   = txtFirstName.Text.ToString(new 
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ta-IN"));
```

Comment: I don't know tamil but I'm just having an idea: May it be so that the bamini font just show tamil characters instead of latin characters? Are the character code values shared? Then it is an codepage / encoding issue...

Comment: @ryadavilli I just updated my query, can you have look on it once again, and help me out?

Comment: What I mean is that in some input methods the fonts "re-use" characters that are in latin languages for other languages.
Could you if possible include the both the text that you write on the webpage and the text that you receive on the server side in your message so we can see what the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use resources file(resources.resx) in visual studio for language conversion and when using different languages.

Comment: No, actually, am not only getting the existing values, I am adding new values to the DB as well. So, whatever data am adding here it should be getting saved in the DB with the same value(in Tamil), is it possible?

Comment: @Shanish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484498/best-way-to-save-a-font-in-sql-server-database, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/3556/storing-arabic-and-chinese-fonts-in-sql-server.aspx refer these links, hope it wil help you.